# "Font not found" when converting HTML to PDF via pandoc

Tags: fonts, latex, pandoc

I want to convert html to pdf using pandoc, but when I use the cmd to convert, I always get an error.

For example, when I try `pandoc C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Pandoc_User's_Guide.html --pdf-engine=xelatex -V CJKmainfont='KaiTi' -o C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Pandoc_User's_Guide.pdf`, I get this error:

```
kpathsea:make_tex: Invalid fontname `'KaiTi'/OT', contains '''
kpathsea:make_tex: Invalid fontname `'KaiTi'/OT', contains '''
Error producing PDF.
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
!
! The font "'KaiTi'" cannot be found.
!
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
!
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................
l.21     \setCJKmainfont[]{'KaiTi'}
```

Then I try to change the code, but I still can't get a pdf document. Could who give me some help?
PS: I have install tex live 2017 and pandoc2.18 in my computer.

Answer (score 1):

The value of the variable is taken verbatim from the string that follows the equal sign, so `-V CJKmainfont='KaiTi'` means that CJKmainfont is set to `'KaiTi'`. Omit the quotes (`-V CJKmainfont=KaiTi`) to get the desired value.

Comment: I have tried it, but it's still wrong and it told me `[WARNING] Missing character: There is no 鈫?pandoc: <stderr>: hPutChar: invalid argument (Invalid argument)`

Comment: @Zhongwc123code Could be an encoding issue. Please make sure that the input is UTF-8 encoded, see [here](https://superuser.com/q/1163753) for how to do that on Windows.